# Fetch records for past days excluding today using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have database which consists of following columns:

```
App Icon, App Title, App Description, Date, Actual Price,
Itunes Link, AppID, UserID, Downloads Count
```

I need to know how many apps were inserted for past 7 days excluding today by Linq query. I tried goggling it and this is the code I found, but I am unable to modify it according to my needs

```
var q = from u in entity.Submit_App
        where u.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) &&
              u.Date <= DateTime.Now
        group u by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(u.Date) into g
        select new ChartTotal()
               {
                    OrderDate = g.Key,
                    Total = g.Sum(y => y.GrandTotal)
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Today` to get date without time part. Also you can introduce new range variable with `let` keyword to simplify your query:

```
var q = from u in entity.Submit_App
        let date = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(u.Date)
        where date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7) &&
              date < DateTime.Today
        group u by date into g
        select new ChartTotal {
            OrderDate = g.Key,
            Total = g.Sum(x => x.GrandTotal)
        };
```

Comment: i get error OrderDate=g.key

will the above querry give me the result of how many apps were uploaded ??

Comment: @SiddharthKoya sorry?

Comment: select new ChartTotal()
        {
            OrderDate = g.Key,//It shows me error in this function
            Total = g.Sum(y => y.GrandTotal)
        };

Comment: :the type nor namespace "ChartTotal() could not be found

Comment: @SiddharthKoya I rolled back question. Your updated was not related to this query

Comment: @SiddharthKoya error says that you are not using namespace where ChartTotal type declared. That is not possible if your original query worked.

Comment: this is not the code i wrote i found it another forum.. i tried to use it for mine..

Comment: @SiddharthKoya then you do understand, that you should define ChartTotal type with appropriate properties?